# GetOpenFileName() crashes when the application unloads a DLL containing C++ code

Tags: c++, exception, winapi, dll

I'm having a strange issue with `GetOpenFileName()` on Windows. If my app loads a DLL using `LoadLibrary()` and then unloads it again using `FreeLibrary()` before calling `GetOpenFileName()`, my app crashes completely when it calls `GetOpenFileName()`. This is what WinDbg reports after the crash:

```
ModLoad: 000007fe`fe2d0000 000007fe`fe369000   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
ModLoad: 000007fe`ffd40000 000007fe`fff17000   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd930000 000007fe`fd966000   C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd970000 000007fe`fd98a000   C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fbdd0000 000007fe`fbefc000   C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fb8a0000 000007fe`fb8cd000   C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`ff640000 000007fe`ff692000   C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd790000 000007fe`fd79f000   C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f1b90000 000007fe`f1c0f000   C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6ff0000 000007fe`f71bb000   C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fbca0000 000007fe`fbce3000   C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fb950000 000007fe`fba42000   C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`fd580000 000007fe`fd5d7000   C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6750000 000007fe`f6ad7000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\GROOVEEX.DLL
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6fd0000 000007fe`f6fe5000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\VCRUNTIME140.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6fc0000 000007fe`f6fc4000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6650000 000007fe`f6744000   C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.DLL
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6530000 000007fe`f6533000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6480000 000007fe`f6483000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6470000 000007fe`f6473000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6590000 000007fe`f6593000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6580000 000007fe`f6583000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6570000 000007fe`f6573000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6560000 000007fe`f6564000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6550000 000007fe`f6554000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6540000 000007fe`f6544000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f3c00000 000007fe`f3c9b000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSVCP140.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f64d0000 000007fe`f64d3000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f64c0000 000007fe`f64c5000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f64b0000 000007fe`f64b3000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f64a0000 000007fe`f64a3000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6490000 000007fe`f6493000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
ModLoad: 000007fe`f6460000 000007fe`f6463000   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
(14e0.15a8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(14e0.15a8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
<Unloaded_test.dll>+0x3e1250:
000007fe`dbc21250 ??              ???
```

I can fix the issue by postponing the `FreeLibrary()` call for the DLL to when my application terminates. Then there will be no more crashes. Still, I'd like to know why loading and unloading that DLL should affect `GetOpenFileName()` at all. It doesn't make sense to me how these things are related.

Could it be related to the fact that the app that loads the DLL and the DLL are somewhat different in nature? The app that loads the DLL is a pure C app compiled using Visual C. The DLL, however, uses C++ code and was compiled using the MSYS2 framework. WinDbg's output somehow seems to hint at the fact that the crash is related to C++ exception handling. However, my app isn't actually calling any C++ code in the DLL. Actually, it's not necessary to call **any** code in the DLL. Just calling `LoadLibrary()` and `FreeLibrary()` right next after each other is enough to produce the issue in `GetOpenFileName()`.

Furthermore, I don't really understand how C++ exception handling in an external DLL should have an influence on `GetOpenFileName()`. Thus, I'd be glad if somebody could shed some light on what's actually going on here.

And here is my question: Is there any way to fix the DLL so that it can be safely unloaded without wreaking havoc in the calling program? Currently, the only way to safely unload the DLL is to unload it at the very end of my program but I'd like to be able to unload the DLL **at any time** without causing crashes in  `GetOpenFileName()`. How can I do that please?

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

So here is an example on how to reproduce it. This is the file `test.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char *lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char szFile[1024];
    HINSTANCE hDLL;
    
    hDLL = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        
    *szFile = 0;
            
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));
        
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST|OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_HIDEREADONLY|OFN_NOCHANGEDIR|OFN_EXPLORER;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0";
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    
    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);    // CRASHES!!!
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the file `dll.c`: (note that `test.c` never calls the DLL export `My_DLL_Function` so you can actually just ignore all the code here; it's just here so that ld pulls all needed dependencies in when linking)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include FT_BITMAP_H

#include <pango/pangocairo.h>
#include <pango/pangoft2.h>

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void My_DLL_Function(void)
{
    PangoContext *context;
    PangoLayout *layout;
    PangoFont *font;
    PangoFontDescription *fontdesc;
    PangoFontMap *fontmap;
    PangoRectangle rc;
    cairo_surface_t *surf;
    cairo_t *cr;
    cairo_matrix_t cm;
    
    fontmap = pango_cairo_font_map_new_for_font_type(CAIRO_FONT_TYPE_FT);
    fontdesc = pango_font_description_from_string("Bitstream Vera Sans 36px");
    
    context = pango_font_map_create_context(fontmap);
    layout = pango_layout_new(context);
        
    pango_layout_set_font_description(layout, fontdesc);
    pango_layout_set_width(layout, 640 * PANGO_SCALE);
    
    font = pango_font_map_load_font(fontmap, context, fontdesc);

    pango_layout_set_markup(layout, "Hello World", -1);             

    pango_layout_get_pixel_extents(layout, &rc, NULL);

    surf = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, rc.width, rc.height);

    cr = cairo_create(surf);
    
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    
    cairo_matrix_init(&cm, 1, 0, 0, 1, -rc.x, -rc.y);
    cairo_set_matrix(cr, &cm);
    
    pango_cairo_show_layout(cr, layout);
    cairo_surface_flush(surf);
    
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surf, "test.png");
    
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf);
    
    g_object_unref(font);
    g_object_unref(layout);
    g_object_unref(context);
    g_object_unref(fontmap);
    pango_font_description_free(fontdesc);
}
```

And this is how you compile everything using MSYS2:

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -lcomdlg32
gcc -DNDEBUG -DGLIB_STATIC_COMPILATION -DGOBJECT_STATIC_COMPILATION -DGIO_STATIC_COMPILATION -DGMODULE_STATIC_COMPILATION -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -I/c/msys64/mingw64/include -I/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -fvisibility=hidden -c -o dll.o dll.c
gcc -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -fPIC -o test.dll dll.o -L/c/msys64/mingw64/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lpixman-1 -lgraphite2 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lbrotlidec -lbrotlienc -lbrotlicommon -lexpat -lthai -ldatrie -lbz2 -lpng -lz -lfribidi -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lpcre2-8 -lpcre2-16 -lpcre2-32 -lpcre2-posix -lffi -luuid -lintl -liconv -lstdc++ -lgcc_eh -lpthread -lgcc_eh -Wl,-Bdynamic -lshlwapi -ldwrite -lWs2_32 -lrpcrt4 -lshell32 -lmsimg32 -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lole32
```

Now run `test.exe` from an MSYS2 console and it will print "Segmentation fault" and crash. This happens every time you run `test.exe` on Windows 10. When calling `FreeLibrary()` after `GetOpenFileName()` there is NO segmentation fault.

Comment: What does the DLL do?

Comment: Currently I'm not calling any DLL function. As I said, just calling `LoadLibrary()` and `FreeLibrary()` on the DLL is enough to provoke the issue and make `GetOpenFileName()` crash.

Comment: What arguments do you pass to `GetOpenFileName`? If the `OPENFILENAME` structure is located in memory "owned" by the DLL, it is clear that an exception happens. The same is true for the buffer for the file name. And if your DLL created a window class, you should destroy all windows of that window class before calling `FreeLibrary`. Maybe such a window is still open or you even pass the handle to that window as "parent window" in the `OPENFILENAME` structure.

Comment: Your C++ DLL likely defines one or more objects with static storage duration, which, inevitable, introduces invisible code. Maybe this is a destructor call into an unloaded module. A [mcve] is required, though. As for exception handling: **Absolutely** no exception is allowed to cross into foreign stack frames. It does not matter whether this is a C++ exception or a C (SEH) exception.

Comment: @IInspectable: The problem with the minimal reproducible example is that the DLL currently is an 8 MB binary containing roughly pango, cairo, fontconfig, pixman, expat, freetype, glib, harfbuzz, fribidi, libpng and zlib so it's going to be very difficult to cut this down into something that be easily reproduced :/

Comment: @MartinRosenau No such thing is true for the `OPENFILENAME` structure. It's definitely not in memory owned by the DLL nor am I using any buffer that is in DLL memory. There is definitely no intersection between the `GetOpenFileName()` call and its accompanying `OPENFILENAME` structure and the DLL. Both is completely separate.

Comment: @Andreas `GetOpenFileName() crashes` -- There is a lot missing here from the question.  First, the `OPENFILENAME` structure needs to be initialized to all zero before you use it.  Did you do that?  Windows uses *everything* in that struct, whether you initialized those members or not.  Then after that, did you specify the size of the struct in the `lStructSize` member?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, this is all correct. I have 25+ years of Win32 API experience. I know how to use `GetOpenFileName()`. That's definitely all correct. No beginners' mistakes or anything. I'm pretty sure that the issue is related to some invisible code injected in that DLL in some destructor or something but this is all very difficult to debug.

Comment: @IInspectable I've now added code to reproduce the issue. It's clearly reproducable on Windows 10 and crashes every time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've now added code that shows how I call `GetOpenFileName()`.

Comment: Take a stack trace at the point of the crash. That will tell you who is trying to call the unloaded DLL. Also, load the symbols for the unloaded DLL to see what function is trying to run. My guess is that the DLL left some code installed, like a FLS callback, which doesn't run until GetOpenFileName does something to trigger it (e.g. create and destroy a thread).

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` is hellaciously complicated.  It's a shell window and loads shell extensions (and initializes COM to communicate with them) which means arbitrary third-party code injected into your process.  Try again without `OFN_EXPLORER` and see if anything changes.

Comment: Actually it'll default to explorer shell if you don't have a hook.  "To display the old-style Open dialog box, enable an OFNHookProcOldStyle hook procedure and ensure that the OFN_EXPLORER flag is not set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: This turned out to be a bug in the Windows backend of glib. The glib DLL registered a vectored exception handler on startup but didn't unregister it when the DLL was unloaded. I've reported it in [#3087](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/3087) and it has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a clue in your flags - you pass OFN_NOCHANGEDIR, but this flag is ignored for GetOpenFileName - it *will* change your application's current directory.

I would bet that one of the many DLLs or other calls you're using makes an asssumption that the working directory is still the application's launch directory (your LoadLibrary call assumes this, so I would guess it's the same elsewhere in your source).

I suspect there's a file operation somewhere in your code whose assumptions about filename are no longer valid the instant you call GetOpenFileName, and that's causing the crash.